# SPO Content Organizer and Send to

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-organizer, content-organizer-rule, send-to-destination

I'm struggling with the Content Organizer in SharePoint Online. We have several "Send To" connections that route documents to other SiteCollections based certain criteria.

Every evening between 9 and 10 the (Online) Content Organizer starts and routes these documents, but sometimes documents are not routed. Then the next evening they are routed. This seems a bit unstable.

Manually routing the documents with the Send To is working just fine.

- Does anyone have this same experience?
- Is there a workaround or other solution?
- Is there an alternative for the Content Organizer only running once a day?

Thanks for your answers :-)